# DNS for localhost while accessing through router or access point on mobile

Tags: xampp, localhost, lan, hosts

i'm running a website in college LAN which is accessed by 200+ members on mobile only.
they are accessing it by server ipaddress `192.168.0.***`.
i wanna assign a name for this ipaddress.
i've tried to modify the `hosts` file. it worked on system alone,but didnt worked on mobile.

 i need some suggestions. im using xampp as server
***everything works on localhost, no internet connection is involved anywhere***

### hosts file

```
127.0.0.1   yep
192.168.0.110 yep.com
```

Comment: what is that <br/> doing in there?

Comment: its an error of stack overflow. i've just added a new line while posting

Comment: Is `'fro'` intentional, or a typo?

Comment: `fro` is intentional, i've used a variable `from` already, that's why using `fro`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot the point before and after the variables.

```
$query="insert into logs(`from`,`to`) VALUES (  '".$caller."',  '".$callto."')";
```

btw change your quote to double quotes just like my code.

Comment: output:
.user1. -->     .user2.
it is inserting including dots

Comment: please make sure that your data is received correctly and that the two originals variables do not have dots before and after them.